# Reorder Columns/Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-bar

```
Country_Of_Data Year  Appr_Country Apprehension
##    <chr>           <chr> <chr>       <dbl>
##  1 Afghanistan     2010  PAN          17
##  2 Afghanistan     2011  PAN           0
##  3 Afghanistan     2010  MEX           3
##  4 Afghanistan     2011  MEX           4
##  5 Afghanistan     2010  US            0
##  6 Afghanistan     2011  US            19
ggplot(Afghan_Appr, aes(Year, Apprehension, fill = Appr_Country)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge')
```

[image]
My outputted plot basically plots three bars per each year but does it in the order of MEX, PAN, US when I want it to be PAN, MEX, US. Is there a way to switch the order? I tried using Afghan$Appr_Country to switch the order, but because of the structure of the data it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fct_relevel` from `forcats` package to switch the order of the df

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(Afghan_Appr, aes(x = Year, y = Apprehension, fill = fct_relevel(Appr_Country, c("PAN", "MEX", "US")))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ?

```
Afghan_Appr[,3] = factor(Afghan_Appr[,3], level= c('PAN','MEX','US'))
ggplot(Afghan_Appr, aes(Year, Apprehension, fill = Appr_Country)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge')
```